# [wordpress]A shortcode that returns a shortcodes combo

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I often use a combination of shortcodes to produce a line of three images. I'd like to simplify the process by creating an other shortcode that would nest the combination. Here's my code :

```
// [imgs img1='' img2='' img3='' height='150']

$output = '[row][col span="1/3"]
[ux_banner bg="'.$url1.'" height="'.$height.'"][/ux_banner]
[/col][col span="1/3"] 
[ux_banner bg="'.$url2.'" height="'.$height.'"][/ux_banner]
[/col][col span="1/3"] 
[ux_banner bg="'.$url3.'" height="'.$height.'"][/ux_banner]
[/col][/row]';
return do_shortcode($output) ;
```

So... well... it doesn't work. I'm a little bit confused about the nested possibilities of do_short_code. Any idea to fix my shortcode ?

Thank you !

Comment: seems you asking to write code for you from `stackoverflow's Uses`?

Comment: Pardon me ? Is my question breaking any rule here ?

Comment: wouldn't see why... what does var_dump($output) and var_dump(do_shortcode($output)) say?

Comment: var_dump($output) shows a well formatted string. But var_dump(do_shortcode($output)) returns {string(1538) " and nothing else. Also the admin became unreachable (white screen with same  {string(1538) "}).